# Add to array method

Tags: java, performance, array, reinventing-the-wheel

The below method is meant to work similar to the way an ArrayList would work with the `add` method: The given double is added to the end of the array. Obviously since you can't add to arrays, a new array is returned with the number added to the end.

I'm worried about using this in loops due to performance, because if I add something hundreds of times, I'll be creating hundreds of array objects. Is this bad? Will it cause issues?

```
public static double[] add(double[] array, double... toAdd)
{
    double[] newArray = new double[array.length + toAdd.length];
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, array.length);
    System.arraycopy(toAdd, 0, newArray, array.length, toAdd.length);
    return newArray;
}
```

Also would this method have advantages/disadvantages of using an ArrayList to add, and then going through every element in the list and copying it to an array?

```
//list.add several things
//array[list.size]
//transfer the list of values to an array:
for(int i = 0 ; i<list.size();i++)
{
    array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Good job on your first post!

Answer (score 5):

Your code is neat, functional, and I really like that you keep everything in the primitive domain (i.e. you use `double[]` instead of `List<Double>`). When dealing with primitives in Java it is almost always faster, and more logical to keep the two domains separate - especially if/when the values are used in calculations.

So, your goal of appending additional `double` values to an array, and returning a new array with the combined contents, is good.

While using `add` seems logical (it's what a `List` calls it) I would recommend you use the name `append` because `add` on a `double` could have different meanings.

As for your implementation, it's correct, and I understand it just fine. In more recent Java versions, it's better to use the `Arrays.copy*` methods though, instead of the `System.arraycopy` routines. This is because the `Arrays` versions are more type safe, and have better in-code semantics. So, your code would be (though you cannot avoid the one `System.arraycopy` call):

```
public static double[] add(double[] array, double... toAdd) {
    double[] newArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + toAdd.length);
    System.arraycopy(toAdd, 0, newArray, array.length, toAdd.length);
    return newArray;
}
```

In Java8, the "nice" way to do this would be:

```
public static double[] add(double[] array, double... toAdd) {
    return DoubleStream.concat(DoubleStram.of(array), DoubleStream.of(toAdd)).toArray();
}
```

About your question for "looping" the values, and adding each of them... well, that will be clear in the logic, but will also be slower. `Arrays.copyOf`, and `System.arrayCopy` both use low-level code to make the memory transfers happen quickly, in bulk, and will outperform a higher-level loop.